# ISO8601 Date Time format D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, iso8601

I'm trying to display a time stamp on my D3 line graph. My data is in JSON. The date looks like this: '2015-04-02T23:10:00'. Currently, it's being formatted like this: 
        var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
When on the graph, it is displayed in this way: 
        Mon Jun 29 2015 09:50:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

I would like to be able to format it so it only shows the time. For example, 09:50:00. I've tried timeFormat to something different and that hasn't worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/format-date-time-axis-with-specified.html)?

Comment: *What* different have you tried?

Comment: @Bergi, I've tried changing d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') to ('%I:%M:%p') and ('%H:%M:%S').

Comment: How are you using this `timeFormat`? Doesn't look like that's the one used for displaying, but rather for parsing.

Comment: When adding the time to the graph, I use this d3.select('#time').text(formatOutput4(d));

formatOutput is this: var formatOutput4 = function (d) { return timeFormat.parse(d.metricDate); };

Comment: And `d.metricDate` is `'2015-04-02T23:10:00'`?

Comment: @Bergi, Yes, correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to distinguish between parsing and stringifying/formatting. So use

```
var inputFormat = d3.time.format.iso; // or d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
var outputFormat = d3.time.format('%I:%M:%p'); // or whatever
```

and then do

```
d3.select('#time').text(formatTime(d));
function formatTime(d) {
    return outputFormat(inputFormat.parse(d.metricDate));
}
```

(though ideally `metricDate` would not be a string, but the resulting date object of parsing the date when loading the raw data)

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting for further reference.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this for me. However, I added this change to my code and it didn't work. I'm assuming this is because of a bigger issue  with my code. The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metricDate' of undefined.

Comment: Nah, I messed it up, the scope of `d` was different. Now looks like the code in your comment.

Comment: That's alright! Which comment? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @CrashleyS: [That one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125119/iso8601-date-time-format-d3#comment50264371_31125119).